# Finding interval convergence $\sum\frac{x^k}{k^k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would I find the interval of convergence for

$\sum\frac{x^k}{k^k}$

I did the ratio test.

$\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)^{(k+1)}}$*$\frac{k^k}{x^k}$

$\frac{x k^k}{(k+1)(k+1)^k}$

I got 
$k\rightarrow\infty$

$x\frac{1}{k+1}\frac{1}{e}$

$=0$

$-1<0(x)<1$

But I am stuck in this part.

Comment: That means the radius of convergence is $\infty$. The series converges everywhere.

Comment: So the interval of convergence would be $[-\infty,\infty]$

Comment: Round brackets, $(-\infty,\infty)$. Another way of seeing it is that if you already know that $\sun \frac{x^k}{k!}$ converges everywhere, this guy goes down faster.